# Why is createView never called?

Tags: kotlin, anko

My ultimate goal is to be able move my content widgets into a custom view and instantiate that view in an Anko layout in my MainView.  I thought I had this working at one point, but I can't reproduce it.

When I run with the following code, the content in the `createView` of the MainContextView is never displayed and I never see the message "creating main context view", but I **do** see the message "main content view".

I start by creating a MainContextView

```
class MainContextView(context: Context) : ViewGroup(context), AnkoComponent<Context> {

    lateinit var textBox: EditText
    lateinit var button: Button
    lateinit var clickCount: TextView

    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<Context>) = with(ui) {
        println("creating main context view")
        verticalLayout {
            themedEditText {
                hint = "hi from main context"
            }
            button = themedButton {
                text = "ok"
            }
            textBox = themedEditText {
                hint = "hi"
            }
            clickCount = themedTextView {
               text = "0"
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onLayout(p0: Boolean, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int, p4: Int) {
        println("onLayout called")
    }

}
```

and call it from my main view

```
class MainView : AnkoComponent<MainActivity> {

    lateinit var mainCtx: MainContextView
    lateinit var textBox: EditText
    lateinit var button: Button
    lateinit var clickCount: TextView
    lateinit var mainMenu: Menu
    lateinit var settingItem: MenuItem
    lateinit var otherItem: MenuItem
    lateinit var floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton

    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<MainActivity>) = with(ui) {
        coordinatorLayout {
            verticalLayout {
                themedAppBarLayout {
                    themedToolbar(theme = R.style.Base_ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dark_ActionBar) {
                        title = resources.getString(R.string.app_name)
                        popupTheme = R.style.AppTheme
                        mainMenu = menu
                        settingItem = mainMenu.add("My Settings")
                        otherItem = mainMenu.add("My Other")
                    }
                }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent)

                // ************************************
                // HERE IS THE CALL TO THE CONTEXT VIEW
                mainCtx = mainContextView { println("main content view ") }
               // *************************************

            }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent) {
            }
            floatingActionButton = floatingActionButton {
                imageResource = android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email
            }.lparams {
                margin = dip(10)
                gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM or Gravity.END
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The MainView is called set as the content view from the  MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var presenter: MainPresenter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val mainView = MainView()
        mainView.setContentView(this)
        presenter = MainPresenter(mainView)

    }

}
```

And finally the ViewManger extensions

```
inline fun ViewManager.mainContextView(theme: Int = 0) = mainContextView(theme) {}

inline fun ViewManager.mainContextView(theme: Int = 0, init: MainContextView.() -> Unit): MainContextView {
    return ankoView({ MainContextView(it) }, theme, init)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem,  it had to do with my subView being defined as a subclass of View/ViewGroup, but not really implementing any of the methods.

As it turns out that was not really the right direction.  The solution is based on a comment on this [issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/issues/267)

Here are some of the key parts of the solution,  I also created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/nPn-/e6145f830bcea70ad33d13d1e1edccb7) with the full code.

The extension function,  creates an instance of the "SubView" class and then calls the `createView()` method in the `ankoView()` method.  It also passes the created instance into the closure that is passed to the extension function, which is key as it allows access to the widgets contained within the view.

```
inline fun ViewManager.mainContentView(theme: Int = 0) = mainContentView(theme) {}

inline fun ViewManager.mainContentView(theme: Int = 0, init: View.(mainContentView: MainContentView) -> Unit): View {
    val mainContentView = MainContentView()
    return ankoView({ mainContentView.createView(AnkoContext.create(it)) }, theme, { init(mainContentView)} )
}
```

The "content view" creates the layout and holds a reference to the widgets.

```
class MainContentView :  AnkoComponent<Context> {

    lateinit var textBox: EditText
    lateinit var button: Button
    lateinit var clickCount: TextView

    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<Context>) = with(ui) {
        verticalLayout {
            button = themedButton {
                text = "ok"
            }
            textBox = themedEditText {
                hint = "hi"
            }
            clickCount = themedTextView {
                text = "0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the main view I have fields to refer to the widgets in the "subView" which I then initialize in the closure passed to the mainContentView instance.

```
lateinit var textBox: EditText
lateinit var button: Button
lateinit var clickCount: TextView
private lateinit var mainMenu: Menu
lateinit var settingItem: MenuItem
lateinit var otherItem: MenuItem
private lateinit var floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton


override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<MainActivity>) = with(ui) {
    coordinatorLayout {
        verticalLayout {
            themedAppBarLayout {
                themedToolbar(theme = R.style.Base_ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dark_ActionBar) {
                    title = resources.getString(R.string.app_name)
                    popupTheme = R.style.AppTheme
                    mainMenu = menu
                    settingItem = mainMenu.add("My Settings")
                    otherItem = mainMenu.add("My Other")
                }
            }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent)
            mainContentView {
                button = it.button
                textBox = it.textBox
                clickCount = it.clickCount
            }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent)
        }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent)
        floatingActionButton = floatingActionButton {
            imageResource = android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email
        }.lparams {
            margin = dip(10)
            gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM or Gravity.END
        }
    }
}
```